# Angular.js: In child controller inside ng-repeat, how to propagate up model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

In my angular application, I am using an ng-repeat and, inside each, a child controller with a form for each item. I'm also using a debounce so that I can auto-save the data. But the issue is that after saving the data (with Restangular), the changes are not propagated back up to the array in the parent. A simple example will work using `angular.copy`, but this has issues with Restangular and its replacement, `Restangular.copy`, does not function exactly the same way. I also tried explicitly setting the item to the right index on the array, but it causes my cursor to lose focus in the input.

Here is a simplified version of my child controller's code. And [here is a full JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jitujaro/1/edit?html,js,output). Is there another approach to solve this problem?

```
$scope.personCopy = angular.copy($scope.person);

// Debounce and auto-save changes
$scope.$watch('personCopy', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal && newVal != oldVal) {
    if (timeout) $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    timeout = $timeout(savePerson, 1000);
  }
}, true);

var savePerson = function() {
  // (In my real app, the following is inside a save callback)
  // Method 1: (doesn't work at all)
  $scope.person = $scope.personCopy
  // Method 2: (works with angular.copy, but not Restangular.copy)
  // angular.copy($scope.personCopy, $scope.person);
  // Method 3: (works, but cursor loses focus)
  // $scope.people[$scope.$index] = $scope.personCopy;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to use a directive? You could put your person controller on the directive, with a scope linking the person instance to the "main" scope. Changes would automatically propagate through `$scope` using a two-way binding.

Comment: That's a good point, but for my own curiosity, do you know how the 2-way binding works behind the scenes?

Comment: See `angular.js` from around line 6200 (v1.2.14), in `nodeLinkFn`. Basically, there's a `$scope.$watch`.

Comment: I tried this (and it arguably made my code a little cleaner), but I ultimately ran into the same issue because I still need to copy the changes from `personCopy` into `person` in order for the auto-save to work properly. http://jsbin.com/jasudaba/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I am not completely getting why you'd not just want to bind to the parent scope, loose the `link` function and `ng-model` the `input` fields to `parent`. You could still use `$scope.$watch` to auto-save to a REST endpoint, either in the `link` function in the directive, or in `ParentController`?

Comment: I made a clone of your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xivujuce/1/edit

Comment: I don't want to update the list until (a) the data is valid and (b) the user has finished (or paused) typing. The reason is that when the list changes, I calculate various totals and also the sorting is updated. Plus, I don't want an ajax request for every keystroke.

Answer (score 4):

Method 3 will work for you if you add "track by" to your ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat='person in people track by $index' ng-controller='EditPersonController'>
```

Here's that working: http://jsbin.com/jitujaro/3/edit

The reason you're losing focus is the DOM for that `ngRepeat` is currently being recreated when you update `people`.  So the element that the focus was on is gone.  When using `track by` Angular knows it doesn't need to recreate those DOM elements.

The reason method 1 and 2 don't work is Javascript's prototypal inheritance.  Upon writing to a variable that is on a parent scope a new local copy of that variable is made on the local scope.  However, when writing to a property of an object that is on a parent scope (as you do in method 3), the write occurs on the parent object as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
angular.extend($scope.person, $scope.personCopy);
```

instead of

```
$scope.person = $scope.personCopy;
```

Comment: I never knew about `angular.extend`. I'll have to make sure it doesn't screw with Restangular like `angular.copy` does, but it seems to work otherwise.